# Search file for string after a certain word

Tags: vb.net

The string im trying to find is 34 characters long and its after the word "file"

how can I display the 34 characters to a single string?

This is what I got so far:

```
 Dim key = "name"
 Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\file.dat")
 TextBox2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd.IndexOfAny("file", 34).ToString
```

This just returns:

```
16379
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

With the help of Steve, I have now got it working with this:

```
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.dat")
    Dim data = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Dim pos = data.IndexOf("file")
    If pos >= 0 Then
        TextBox2.Text = data.Substring(pos, 39).Replace("file""", "")
    End If
```

now I just need to be able to loop this and return them into arrays / other textboxes is there is more than one instance of this, I have no idea on how this could be done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your code in single steps, so it is more clear what you have to do

```
dim data = sr.ReadToEnd()
dim pos = data.IndexOfAny("file")
if pos >= 0 then
  TextBox2.Text = data.Substring(pos, 34)
```

Comment: That works great just had to make a few modifications, but what if my file had more than one set of strings i needed? Like having another word called "file" later in the file then a different string after it?

Comment: The [IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56y4ddbk.aspx) has an overload that takes the starting point to execute the search. Thus, if you have a loop and at each loop use the value of `pos + 39` variable as the starting point for the next call to IndexOfAny you could find every occurrence of you text blocks. (39=4 chars for file + 1 space + 34 char of the string found)